# Select object element whit string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have this object

```
const body = { el1: 'first', el2: 'second', el3: 'third' }
```

I want get `"first"` using "dynamic selector", like this

```
const selector = 'body.el1'

console.log([selector])
```

of course I can just do `console.log(body.el1)` but in my function `selector` change, so how can I get that?

Thanks in advance